# Awk date validation

Tags: bash, awk

I have an awk script where I need to validate a large number of lines containing dates.

I'm currently using either a regex based solution to do a basic validation (without testing for leap years or ) or calling the UNIX date command to validate it more accurately. The date command works well, but calling a system command is pretty expensive in terms of performance.

I was hoping that someone here might be able to suggest a solution that is both accurate and is fast.

Here's an example of my data

```
20140804024614
20140803190020
20140803163320
20140803083222
20140803170321
20140803234044
20140804011857
20140803204008
20140803160026
20140803140120
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using GNU awk? If so, https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html

Comment: Please show your attempts, maybe you are using an over-complicated call to syscall.

Comment: How did you made this format working with `UNIX date` ?

Comment: Are those additional numbers times? If so, do you need to validate those too? In DST zones 2:30am, for example, would be invalid on the day when the clocks go forward since at 2am the time jumps forward to 3am. Wouldn't it make sense to include some examples of invalid dates in your sample input and also post the output you'd expect from a tool given that input? At least a statement of which segment of each line is the date would be good - e.g. is the date on the first line 2014-08-04 in YYYY-MM-DD format or 2014-04-08 or 2014-04-02 or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your reply. yes the other fields are the time - "yyyyMMddhhmmss". I do not need to worry about time zones since it's already taken into consideration by another system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a whole lot of assumptions about your input file, this is probably all you need to print only the valid dates+times using GNU awk for time functions and gensub():

```
awk 'strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S",mktime(gensub(/(.{4})(..)(..)(..)(..)/,"\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 ",""))) == $0' file
```

It will only work with dates since the epoch.

If you need to print some kind of "valid/invalid" message for each date/time:

```
$ cat file
20140230035900
20140804024614
$
$ awk '{print (strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S",mktime(gensub(/(.{4})(..)(..)(..)(..)/,"\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 ",""))) == $0 ? "" : "in") "valid:", $0}' file
invalid: 20140230035900
valid: 20140804024614
```

The above works by converting the date+time to seconds since the epoch, then converting those seconds to a date+time in the original format and if the result is identical to what you started with then the original date was valid.

Comment: Hi, this looks like a pretty useful solution. However, it does not seem to work as a date such as "20140230035900" which contains the 30th of Feb is marked as valid.

Comment: FYI, the input file contains a number of columns. The date field is actually split into two columns with other cotent on either side.

Comment: Thanks. The edited version works perfectly. I've noted to add the erroneous data next time.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
checkFormat ()
{
dateV="${1}"

echo "${dateV}"|gawk  '{
   if (match($0,/^((?:19|20)[0-9][0-9])(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([01][0-9]|2[0-4])$/,a)) {
      year=a[1]+0
      mon=a[3]+0
      day=a[4]+0
      hour=a[5]+0
      }
   else {
       print "KO: "$0
       exit
     }

   if (day == 31 && (mon == 4 ||  mon == 6 || mon == 9 || mon == 11))
      print "KO: "$0 # 30 days months
   else if (day >= 30 && mon == 2)
      print "KO: "$0 # Febrary never 30 o 31
   else if (mon == 2 && day == 29 && ! (  year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)))
      print "KO: "$0 # Febrary  29 leap year
   else
      print "Correct date !:" $0
   }'

}


checkFormat 2014080417
checkFormat 20140803190035
```

Usage:

```
$ ./checker.sh 
Correct date !:2014080417
KO: 20140803190035
```

NOTE: `MINUTES` and `SECONDS` will be your task :)

Check also: http://nixtip.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/an-awk-date-format-validator/

Comment: if you just wanna check for short-months (anything < 31 days), just do ::::::::::::: :::::::::::::: ::::::::::::  `function __(_) { return _%2~(7<_) }` - that's literally all you need … and if you don't care for `nawk` at all, even more concise :::: `function __(_) { return _%2~7<_ }`

Comment: conversely, long months check is `function ___(_) { return _%2~_<8 }`

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this regex should cover ***ANY*** year, with or without left-padded zeros, in lieu of calculating the leap-year indicator :

```
awk '/(([2468][048]|[13579][26]|(^|[0+-])[48])(00)?|0000|^[+-]?0*)$/'
```

To my genuine surprise,

- `gawk` went much faster with the `regex` than the standard formula
- `nawk` is roughly the same speed between the 2 methods, and
- only `mawk` seem to favor doing math