# Validate datetime through bash script(i.e. '20200204a')

Tags: bash

[Validate date format in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18731346/391104)

```
$ date "+%Y%m%d" -d "20200204" > /dev/null  2>&1 ; echo $?
0

$ date "+%Y%m%d" -d "202002/04" > /dev/null  2>&1; echo $?
1

$ date "+%Y%m%d" -d "20200204a" > /dev/null  2>&1 ; echo $?
0
```

As you can see the invalid input datetime string `"20200204a"` passed the test.

Question> Is there a way that I can add more strict testing on this input?

Thank you

Comment: Have an additional check that your input text is 8 character in length.

Comment: If you are looking for a specific format, you could add some kind of regex check. Something like: `grep -E '^[0-9]{8}$' <<< 20200204a`.  Then check if it is a valid date with `date`.

Comment: This is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761659/awk-date-validation)
Where is solved with AWK

Answer (score 0):

The `+%` format controls the output, not input.

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -MTime::Piece -e '
    $d = shift;
    Time::Piece->strptime($d, "%Y%m%d")->strftime("%Y%m%d") eq $d
    or exit 1
' "20210229" 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 you can do this :

```
echo "20200204" | python3 -c '
import sys
import datetime
try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(sys.stdin.read().rstrip(), "%Y%m%d")
except ValueError:
    exit(1)'
```

It will return 1 when there are errors.